# How to create this type of Layout in android

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I create layout like below Image. Is there any ListView example like in below Image? And, how can i create Button at footer in android?

Can anyone give me some idea of what is used in this IMAGE i am not getting it.

[image: layout]

Comment: these aren't buttons that you "code" these are onscreen buttons of the new ICS firmware on the new nexus , or you can have them by flashing a mod. For the image in a list view it's just a regular lineyar layout(horizontal orientation) layout with a textview and a imageview (it's an item of the listview)

Comment: [There are lot of examples related to this](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+listview+with+images+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) Please check that. And, search in google before asking here.

Comment: but why its looks different from regular

Comment: Because, they're customized the listview with images. And, the listview page occupies some space in that layout. And, the remain space are occupied by footer and some textview or anything..

Comment: Spk whythis all looks differentfrom above listview ?

Comment: See the `user-rekaszeru` answer. Its enough for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve such result using `RelativeLayout`, and inside of it arranging the child views in a flat (meaning effective and fast) structure relatively to each other:

You have

- a `logo` image with `alignParentTop = true`,
- a `security` image or button with `layout_below` set to `logo`,
- a `control` button with `alignParentBottom = true`, and finally
- a `list` listview with `layout_below` set to `security` and `layout_above` set to control, having a `layout_height` of `fill-parent` of `match-parent`.

**Edit**: The `ListView` control above also uses custom a item renderer holding -probably- a `TextView` with a custom image set as `drawableLeft`.

Comment: +1 Nice answer with perfect explanation.

Comment: u can see how it is arranged , i can increase the height of Each item ok so still wont get same UI

Comment: Focus on the parent container being a `RelativeLayout` and the order + relation of the items added there. It's really not about sizing the children views, but arranging them relatively to each other. See `@Lord Flash`'s sample code: it has a good start, but needs duplicate `@id` declarations to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it's ListView. Try something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/title" >
    </ListView>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: actually, it's a custom `ExpandableListView`

Comment: that's right, but you should remove the **+** sign from the `android:layout_below="@+id/title"` in the `ListView` declaration, and also from the `android:id="@+id/footer"` in the `LinearLayout` footer declaration, because they all have already been declared earlier.